# rust clap How to specify the type of command line arguments

Tags: rust, clap

I am using rust's clap to investigate command line arguments. is it possible to specify which one will be input as a command line argument in clap?
Is it possible to specify the type like `type=int` in the following python code?

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--some_string", type=str, required=True, )
```

What I am looking for is to specify the type of the command line arguments at the stage of defining them, as in the above python code.

I would like to use clap to do the following

```sh
./target/release/~~ --i32_args 12 --f32_args -32.5
```

Thus, if the type and variable match, we want it to work without error.

```sh
./target/release/~~ --i32_args -32 --f32_args 1
```

In this case, I want to cause an immediate panic and terminate the operation.
What I am looking for is something that does not use methods such as `value_of`, but judges the type of the command line argument at the time the command is executed, and executes it if the type is correct, or panic immediately if the type is wrong.

It is my understanding that in `value_of_t`, the type is not determined until the data is retrieved. Therefore, I think it is different from what I am looking for.

Comment: Please clarify, as you seem to have two separate questions in your question description. I am unsure of what you want exactly. What did you mean by "specify[ing] which one will be input as a command line argument"? For your second question, yes. You can do that. Look at the project's [README](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap), it has many great examples.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but you can use `value_parser` with Clap v4

```
use clap::{arg, value_parser, Command}; // Clap v4
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;

fn main() {
    let matches = Command::new("clap-test")
        .arg(
            arg!(--ip <VALUE>)
                .default_value("127.0.0.1")
                .value_parser(value_parser!(Ipv4Addr)),
        )
        .arg(
            arg!(--port <VALUE>)
                .required(true)
                .value_parser(value_parser!(u16)),
        )
        .arg(arg!(--f32 <VALUE>).value_parser(value_parser!(f32)))
        .get_matches();

    println!(
        "ip {:?}, port {:?}, float {:?}",
        matches.get_one::<Ipv4Addr>("ip").expect("required"),
        matches.get_one::<u16>("port").expect("required"),
        matches.get_one::<f32>("f32"),
    );
}
```